# AngularJS send window.location to a function or a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a "Back" button as a function or directive. Upon clicking it, it would call a function that has several things to do before redirecting the user to a url.
Normally, in pure JS, I would have a simple div with an onclick function to which I would pass the URL to go to then the function would do its thing then make a window.location.href = url and it would be ok.
Here in angular, the URL i'm trying to send is part hardcoded, part coming from a ng-model: `url="#/clients/editer/{{client._id}}"`

When trying to use a simple function to which I would pass this as a string, my function doesent get the client.id as a string though the HTML inspector of firefox says it does. But if I console.log the URL the function gets, it says
`"#/clients/editer/{{client._id}}"` instead of `"#/clients/editer/56684b4fe7b59ff020b85590"`

When trying to use a directive instead of a function, as being new to all this, I dont understant how I'm supposed to pass thir URL to the directive. Since the URL could change radically from a module to another (from `"#/clients/editer/{{client._id}}"` to `"#/materiel/editer/{{materiel._id}}"`, I need to pass the decoded URL directly to the directive which would then execute the onclick function.

Hope someone can help me !

Comment: Please post all your relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made simple test code

js

```
scope.client._id = 9;

scope.somefunction = function (url){
    console.log(url)
}
```

Html

```
<div ng-click="somefunction('#/clients/editer/{{client._id}}')">link</div>
```

Result: #/clients/editer/{{client._id}}

```
<div ng-click="somefunction('#/clients/editer/'+ client._id)">link</div>
```

Result: #/clients/editer/9

Is this the result you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Hi Imants, Yes exactly it does the trick and I dont know why my code didnt work as it was 99% the same as yours... Seems to work with minor adaptations thx. Now what if I want to build a directive using this type of behavior ?

Comment: @BlackPage about why it didn't work, angular thought that string was just a string, and it wasn't rendered. About directive, you want that directive to use address given by string or something?

Comment: @BlackPage if this is correct answer, please mark this as an answer.

Comment: the directive would have to get exactly what you suggested that is `'#/clients/editer/'+ client._id`